# Lines from each file doesn't appear in the same line while merging two files

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, join, sed

I have a problem when merging two files with ubuntu 'join' command. This has bothered me for a week. Actually I often use this command for file editing and this is the first time I met this problem. I have two files look like this(space separated here for example):

file1

```
A A A
B B B
...
```

file2

```
A D D
B E E
...
```

The files have 20+ columns, hundreds of rows (utf-8 character set, tab separted). I use join command to merge two files based on the first column. The result should be like this:

```
A A A D D
B B B E E
```

But I got this:

```
A A A
 D D
B B B
 E E
```

I tried output two files then merge with 'pasted' command and got the same results. Also, I didn't see any newline character at the first/end of each line. I tried `sed -i 's/\n\t/\t/g' file`. It doesn't work. 
They still don't show in the same line ! Have you guys met his problem before? what could be the possible reason?

my command looks like this:

```
join -1 3 -2 1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.2,2.3,2.4 -t $'\t' <(sort -k3,3 file1) <(sort -k1,1 file2)  

paste -d"\t" file1 file2
```

Comment: I don't see any `join` command in your question ......

Comment: Put the _join_ command into your question (formatted as code).

Comment: Ok, I have used this join command for a long time ,this is the first time I met this problem.

Comment: What does `file file1 file2` say about the files?

Comment: @Neng : You specify tab as field separator for `join`, but leave it set to a space for the `sort` command. I don't see how this explains **that** result, but it for sure looks odd.

Comment: @Neng: I could not reproduce your result, with the data you have posted. I must admit that I did not do process substitution (which does not work on my platform), but I get the result which you expected (BTW, in I tested it in both bash and zsh). Maybe you should do a `tail -n 2 file1|xxd` to check whether you have some odd characters in the file.

Comment: @user1934428, well, I guess it's the problem of character set.  The original file is excel format, I convert it to text(tab-delimited). Then I changed the coding format from GB2312 to utf-8 in notepad++, so this maybe cause some odd characters in files. I guess I have to try other file format.

Comment: @Neng : Instead of trying out blindly different formats, I would look into the currently exported files and identify, which characters are incorrect. If your locale is set to UTF8, and the tabs are still tabs (very likely), you should not get surprising newlines in the output. Ah, and in my comment, I made a mistake: It makes more sense to do the check with a `head` instead of a `tail`.